# Dojo FilteringSelect CSS Styles

Tags: css, dojo

**What are all the css style classes that has to be changed to restyle dojo filtering select ?**

Note: I am using claro theme.

I want to

1.Set the style for one particular filteringselect with id QuickSearchPane_SelectBox

2.Set the style for all other filteringselect

I found a few like:
`.claro .dijitTextBox .dijitInputInner`

`.claro .dijitInputField .dijitPlaceHolder`

`.claro .dijitSelect`

But these are not giving the desired effect. I am not even able to change the background colors.

For Menu

```
[dijitpopupparent="QuickSearchPane_SelectBox"] > .dijitComboBoxMenu .dijitMenuItem
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS class to start styling your `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`;

This example will style all instance of `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofgcd24n/

```
.dijitInputInner {
  background-color: green !important;
}

.dijitMenuItem {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

This other example below will style only ONE instance of `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`, please note the use of Descendant combinator as selector (where you use the ID for your widget DOM):

```
#widget_stateSelect .dijitInputInner {
    /* your style*/
}
```

Generally you can use (in Chrome Dev Tool) Event Listen Breakpoints for click/mouse down, so when you open you FilteringSelect, you can block execution, and check with the inspector its HTML structure and see additional CSS classes you want to override with your styles.

More about CSS selector:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

If you need more details, please post your HTML and CSS and desired layout so we can work out a specific solution.